# Is std::make_pair creating copies when the objects are added to a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

my problem is that i want to add something to map:

I dont know if std make pair is creating copies of the obejct? It should only add the pointer to the map and should create a copy of the long64 SOR. 
Im using pointers because references are not working!

`typedef std::map<SOR, kPartBase*> Partlist; //the map`

```
void kFixedConstruct::push_part(kPartBase& part)
{
    Parts.insert(std::make_pair<SOR, kPartBase*>(static_cast<long64>(part.SorID), &part)); //Is this like really inserting the pointers to the originals or is it creating a copy?
}
```

Comment: Creating a copy of what? It seems that your `SOR` type is probably an alias of `long64`, which is probably a `int64_t` or similar. Therefore, the both key and value of your `map` are simple value types (some sort of integer, and a raw pointer). There is no functional difference between copy and move for simple value types.

Comment: Can you think of a simple experiment that would answer your question?

Comment: Unrelated: `kPartBase& part` isn't shouting "I have a long lifetime!" at me, so I'll drop a reminder to make sure `part` isn't an variable with a shorter lifetime (like an Automatic) than `Parts`.

Comment: @JMAA yeah SOR is an alias. I was scared that it would copy the variable part

Comment: @user4581301 Dont worry, part will be destroyed if the object is

Comment: I'm not worried about `part` NOT being destroyed. I'm worried about it being destroyed while `Parts` still holds a pointer to it.

Comment: @user4581301 "*I'm worried about it being destroyed while `Parts` still holds a pointer to it*" - then you should be managing the object's lifetime using a smart pointer. Either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. Probably the latter in your case, but hard to tell for sure since you didn't show how the map is populated or used. You can store smart pointers in a `std::map`.

Comment: The map is part of an element called kFixedConstruct - they exists in a hierachical tree - only when a FixedConstruct is deleted all its parts and the map are deleted , and ive build in some nullptr checks. Maybe shared ptr is a good idea but dont know how it works :/

Comment: I'll take you at your word that you have the lifetime covered, but don't count on null pointer checks to find dangling pointers. Pointers only go one way; there is no back channel to set them to null if their target goes away.

Comment: If an object is deleted, pointers to it are not set to `nullptr`. It seems like you need to go and read up on a good introduction to C++ pointers, as much of what you're saying suggests deep misunderstandings of what they are and how they work.

Comment: "Maybe shared ptr is a good idea but dont know how it works" - it looks like you're also not clear on how raw pointers work. `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` are much safer, especially if you're not entirely sure how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be several copies of your data.  To see them all, lets break this down into individual steps.

First we create a pair from your two values:

```
std::pair<SOR, kPartBase*> first(static_cast<long64>(part.SorID), &part);
```

Then, since this isn't the right type for `map::insert`, we copy them again to a different variable:

```
std::pair<const SOR, kPartBase*> second(first);
```

because a map::value_type has a const key value.   This copy can be avoided by using

```
Partlist::value_type(static_cast<long64>(part.SorID), &part)
```

in place of `make_pair`.  This pair (`second`) will be copied into your map.

Or you can use

```
Parts.emplace(static_cast<long64>(part.SorID), &part);
```

(or `try_emplace`) and avoid all but the copy needed to put the values into the map.

Comment: While technically correct (and solid advice), I suspect that OP was concerned that the object pointed at by the reference `part` would be copied, which it wont.